# How to iterate over two arguments in the sh linux shell

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I have two sets of arguments: `a = "5 7 1"` and `b = "dogs cats horse"`

They should come in pairs: `5` matches `dogs`, `7` matches `cats` and `1` matches `horse`

They also should do this in one line:

```
I have 5 whatever dogs whatever whatever
I have 7 whatever cats whatever whatever
I have 1 whatever horse whatever whatever
```

The problem is that the `$a` and `$b` can have hundreds of arguments, so writing many lines like the above ones isn't really an option.

I found something like the following which do the job:

```
a = "5 7 1"
b = "dogs cats horse"

set -- $a
for i in $b; do
  echo "I have $i whatever $1 whatever whatever"
  shift 1
done
```

but I wonder if there's some other alternatives.

Basically when we have just 3 pairs, it's easy to know in the script which values from `$a` correspond to which values of `$b`. Now imagine having 200 of values in both sets and you have to change the `$b` values where `$a` values are `50` and `157`. Of course it's just an example -- any values can change in both sets with time. So is there a better way to map the values something like `5:dogs`, `7:cats` and `1:cats`? In this way if numbers of dogs changes to 4 I can easily find what to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use 'bash', you can use the associative array (and mapfile/readarray), but this will not scale well to the number of items you mention (200+).

For a solution that is not bash specific: Consider storing the pairs in a file (or inline document, see below).

```
dogs:5
cats:7
horse:1
```

Then use a script:

```
while IFS=: read k v ; do
  echo "I have $v whatever $k whatever whatever"
done < file.txt
```

You can also embed the map into << document.

```
while IFS=: read k v ; do
  echo "I have $v whatever $k whatever whatever"
done <<EOF
dogs:5
cats:7
horse:3
EOF
```

Comment: I think this solution would be good, but I have to store the values in the main script instead of some additional file. So what's the best way to do that?

Comment: You can use here document. After the loop body add <<EOF, fillowed by the data then EOF line

Answer (score 2):

Might use something like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

a="5 7 1"
b="dogs cats horse"

c=( $a )
d=( $b )

for i in ${!c[@]}; do
    echo "There are ${c[$i]} of ${d[$i]}"
done
```